# (UE4)Check if a point lies in a collision circle

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

is there an easy way to check if a point lies in a collision circle of other actors in the world? I am working on a project where my actor would move to a certain location and i want to check if i would get a collision even before my actor is moving.

Answer (score 2):

If the distance between the two objects is less than the collision radius, the objects would "collide". Unless you have other criteria?